# Where is iptables in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, iptables

I'm reading through the source code that writes directly to system `iptables` in `/system/xbin/iptables` in Android. I would like to do the same in Ubuntu without using the `iptables` command.

Where is `iptables` located on Ubuntu 16.04? I followed some questions and answers which don't apply on this version of Ubuntu.

`find / -name iptables` return `/sbin/iptables` which contains binary and maybe man!

Where is the file that the  `iptables` command writes its configuration?

Comment: According to what I see on my device, `/system/xbin/iptables` is a binary. I think the kernel stores the iptables in RAM as opposed to a place on the drive?

Comment: it stored on disk in android!, that mean rules need to be written  after each reboot by my application?

Comment: Ah, I get what you mean now. Okay.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`iptables` stores its information in RAM, meaning it's non-persistent. If you want to save/restore it at will, you'll need to use a couple commands.

First off, you would use `iptables` as normal to set up your rules the way you want them. Then, you can freeze these rules using something like:

```
sudo iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/iptables.conf
```

Then, to load your rules, it's a simple matter of running:

```
sudo iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.conf
```

You can add this to your `/etc/rc.local` or similar to have it run automatically at boot, or you can have your program call this executable (or just pass the same `iptables` rules over and over again).

Answer (score 4):

Instead of iptables, you should actually take consideration in using ufw, [the default firewall configuration tool](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html#firewall-ufw) provided by ubuntu internally.

All of the settings on firewall, which was configured through iptables, could be stored through ufw, such as the configuration file located at `/etc/default/ufw`.

NAT is also possible to be configured and stored: https://gist.github.com/kimus/9315140

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is stored on disk for `iptables` unless you save the rules like so:

```
service iptables save
```

After you reboot, the rules that you save will be back in place. You can see that by doing an `iptables -L` to list the rules.

The rules are actually stored on disk (if saved) in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`.